# Django Admin keep logout repeatedly. May because the DB is damaged. How to fix this situation?

Tags: python, sql-server, django

Let me describe how this problem Admin logout problem occurred.

It was about few months ago. My DB is MSSQL.

I was using Django 1.11, and I wish to update to Django 3.x .

First I was updating my Django to 3.1, because of that,

I have to switch django-pyodbc-azure to django-mssql-backend.

And I did migrate after I update my Django to 3.1.

But I didn't know that mssql-backend does not supporting Django 3.1.

So I switch my Django from 3.1 to 3.0.x

And I remember that I have to migrate again.

But my own models' migrations are the same.

I didn't add any new migrations in my models.

So the Django has create some migrations that does not belong to me,

and also unreachable for me.

I realized Django has create some migrations after I did migrate.

The migrate applies something like:

admin. {nums}_logentry_add_action_flag_choices

auth. {nums}_alter_user_last_name_max_length

auth. {nums}_alter_group_name_max_length

auth.{nums}_update_proxy_permissions

member.{nums}_auto_YYYYMMDD_HHMM.py
- (something with Change managers on membergroup)

At this moment. I haven't login through Admin page.

And I think I did more Django version changes after this (maybe two times again).

Just because I was trying to find out which version is suit for me.

After all this changing between 3.1 and 3.0,

my docker is not compatible with my server and DB,

And the Admin logout problem showed up.

So I have to rewind my Django back to 1.11.

And of course, some of the migrate I mentioned up there,

have to be done again.

So I don't really remember how many times I migrate before I found out the Admin logout problem.

Anyway, I think I messed up something during the migrates.

And it doesn't matter which Version of Django I use,

3.0.x ~ 3.1.x all have the same Admin logout problem when I connect to the DB.

Only when I switched back to Django 1.11, the Admin logout problem will disappear.

**Why I think the Database is damaged?**

Because I create a new docker image that has Django 3.0.

And I create a whole new MSSQL DB, same migrations, the Django Admin works fine.

But if I use the same docker container. Connect to the old Database, then Django Admin starting to have the logout problem.

At the first I did think it was Django's problem, I tried some method. But none of them can solve the problem.

I can't remember all of them, but for example:

https://groups.google.com/g/django-users/c/F9XCiLDbkbY?pli=1

[Django development server keeps logging out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18247190/django-development-server-keeps-logging-out)

My Admin logout problem also have the 302 status code.
[302 status code, when I browsing in the Admin and got logout.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ksPDK.png)
Just like the article on google.

Because the old DB, is a customer's Database, I can't tell them I damaged their DB,

and ask them to move all the Data to a new created DB.

Even I could ask the customer to do that, I still not sure after the Data moved to the new DB,

this Admin problem will not show up again.

So I would like to ask for help.

1. Is there anyway to redo all the migrate for a DB, but without losing Data?
2. Is there any method I still can try?

Answer (score 0):

My problem its same. I solved update version postgres 9.5  to 14. Working fine.